# Data transformation in R - grouping variable by ID

Tags: r, reshape

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I'm not sure what to search for or how to solve it.

My data looks something like this:

```
Date     UserID   Var1   Var2
2013-01  1        2      3
2013-02  1        2      1
etc.
```

Where the dates that are recorded are different for each user.

I want to find statistics about one of the variables (let's say Var2), and in order to do that I want to reshape the data, so that the output will be something like:

```
ID   Time1   Time2   Time3   ...
1    3       1       NA
etc.
```

where Time1 is the first date that a user appears in the data, Time2 is the next, etc.

Comment: You want to find statistics about the variables or just reshape the data for one of the variables (which is what your example does)?

Comment: @rawr - I edited to clarify. Hopefully that helps. I want to find statistics, but I want to reshape first.

Comment: @Jealie - something like that, but where the data is all grouped by ID, instead of just showing one ID at a time.

Comment: You should look at the `reshape2` library.  The `melt()` function is pretty good at doing this kind of stuff.  You just need to know what variables you want to identify and which ones are measure variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**edited to handle the re-alignment of dates on a relative scale**)

What about using `reshape`?

This is to input the data:

```
> zz <- "Date     UserID   Var1   Var2
+ 2013-01  1        2      3
+ 2013-02  1        2      1
+ 2013-02  2        2      1"
> Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

This is to reshape:

```
Data2 = reshape(Data[c(1,2,4)],direction='wide',timevar='Date',idvar='UserID')
```

Resulting in:

```
> Data2
  UserID Var2.2013-01 Var2.2013-02
1      1            3            1
3      2           NA            1
```

(note that `c(1,2,4)` refers to the colum numbers corresponding to `Date`, `UserID` and `Var2`)

Finally, to obtain the desired output, you can simply move the `NA` to the end of each line:

```
t(sapply(1:nrow(Data2), function(x) c(Data2[x,!is.na(Data2[x,])],rep(NA,sum(is.na(Data2[x,]))))))
```

Resulting in:

```
     UserID Var2.2013-01 Var2.2013-02
[1,] 1      3            1           
[2,] 2      1            NA
```

Note that the column names here are not current anymore. Also, you may possibly have columns containing only NA on the right of your matrix... I will let you handle these small details.

Comment: The only problem is that looks like it will group variable 2 by the date variable, right?

My goal is to have column 1 be the first Var2 for userID X, regardless of what the date is. For example, if UserID 1's earliest record was on 2013-03 and UserID 2's earliest was 2013-04, these values would still both show up in the T1 column.

Comment: I have edited the answer to take this into account. Is it what you were looking for?